# application of algebra to cryptography

Tags: cryptographic-hardware

I have taken some courses on algebra like abstract algebra, linear algebra etc. I want to know more on the application of algebra to cryptography.I don't know if anyone can be of help. thanks.

Comment: Flagged as too broad. Take any crypto textbook and see what you find.

Comment: You can be pleased to know that there is extensive application of algebra in cryptography, especially concepts like groups and fields. As @fkraiem said, the question is too broad to get an answer here, but there are concepts that you can look up to get more information: public key encryption, key agreement, zero knowledge proofs and commitments.

Comment: what of if i limit it to application of linear algebra to cryptography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by taking a look at public-key cryptosystems like RSA or ElGamal, they are defined over an algebraic group and are based on the group properties. You will see how many concepts from algebra are involved, e.g., the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the Discrete Logarithm Problem...